# N=4 d=3 susy algebra

Tags: research-level, supersymmetry, superalgebra

Does anybody know how to derive the $\mathcal{N}=4$ d=3 susy algebra doing a dimensional reduction from the most famous $\mathcal{N}=4$ d=4?

Equivalently, does it exist a reference in the literature in which such an algebra is explicitly written out?

Thanks